# how to display newest items from 4 tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i created a div on my homepage to display the most recent items from four tables on my database, but i'm having problems with the structure of the query, i tried this for the model:

```
   $sql = "(SELECT name,type, screenshot,url from music WHERE status = 1   ) 
    UNION ALL (SELECT name,type, screenshot,url from lyrics WHERE status = 1   )
    UNION ALL(SELECT name,type, screenshot,url from mixtapes WHERE status = 1  ) 
    UNION ALL (SELECT name,type, screenshot, vurl from videos WHERE  status = 1  ) ORDER BY 'date_added' desc LIMIT 8";
     $query = $this->db->query($sql);
     return $query->result();
```

this query retrieves only from the  music table, and the limit keyword applies only to the items retrieved from the music table, but i want the query run as one query, so that the items are retrieved based on the latest items from the four tables and the limit keyword limits the results to eight items, please how do i construct the query, or is there any other way to do it? please help..

Comment: do the tables have the same schema?

Comment: no, they do not..by schema you mean the number of columns and their various types ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two recent items of each list; you can use something like this:

```
(SELECT name,type, screenshot,url from music 
    WHERE status = 1 order by date_added desc limit 0,2) 
UNION
(SELECT name,type, screenshot,url from lyrics  
    WHERE status = 1 order by date_added desc limit 0,2)
UNION
(SELECT name,type, screenshot,url from mixtapes 
    WHERE status = 1 order by date_added desc limit 0,2) 
UNION
(SELECT name,type, screenshot,url from videos 
    WHERE status = 1 order by date_added desc limit 0,2)
```

Or, if you want the recent 8 items from all 4 tables:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT name,type, screenshot,url from music WHERE status = 1) 
    UNION
    (SELECT name,type, screenshot,url from lyrics WHERE status = 1) 
    UNION
    (SELECT name,type, screenshot,url from mixtapes WHERE status = 1) 
    UNION
    (SELECT name,type, screenshot,url from videos WHERE status = 1) 
) ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,8;
```

Comment: hmm..thanks, but please, what if i want the  div to display, based on when it was entered, like if a song was entered, it will show as the first item, and if a mixtape was entered after the song, it will now become the first item, just like that..

Comment: That's another question. please open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT name,type, screenshot,url from music WHERE status = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name,type, screenshot,url from lyrics WHERE status = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name,type, screenshot,url from mixtapes WHERE status = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name,type, screenshot, vurl from videos WHERE  status = 1
    ) t
    ORDER BY 'date_added' desc
    LIMIT 8
";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->result();
```

Comment: hello, im getting a syntax error "syntax error, unexpected 'name' (T_STRING)" after the opening parenthesis..

Comment: tried that, still the same result, it still picks items from only the music table

Comment: This won't work if there are 4 lyrics inserted later than the others.